# Concat'ing intergers to make a string

Tags: c++

This is what I am trying to do:

```
int x = 0;
char toBuffer;
while (twenty_byte_buffer[x] != '\0') // While the string isn't at the end...
{
cout << int(twenty_byte_buffer[x]); // show me, works fine

//need to concat the int values from above into toBuffer as a string
//eg. "-62-8711097109" would have derived from this "©nam"

//this doesn't work:
//strcat ( toBuffer, reinterpret_cast<*????*>(twenty_byte_buffer[x]) );

x++;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: My brain just turned inside-out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `stringstream`.  It works just like `cout`:

```
stringstream sstr;
while (twenty_byte_buffer[x] != '\0')
{
    sstr << int(twenty_byte_buffer[x]);
    x++;
}

string result = sstr.str();
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the right solution -- see my answer at #4996093. (+1, though, because I based my answer on yours.)

Comment: My goal is to match (`==`) strings which have some 2 byte unicode chars that are showing up in them, eg. `"©nam"` which when translated to a concat'ed `int` becomes `"-62-8711097109"`. When made into a string, I can quickly parse without jumping through hoops to deal with the unicode UTF-16 conversions. Not sure if this is the right approach, but it sure seems like the easiest approach. The key here is that I am looking for predefined footprints. I can just run through my string looking for `"-62-8711097109"`. I believe, so far, that this answer is the best answer.

Comment: @cube: I can't make heads or tails of most of that. I'm not sure what "@nam" is, although I know `@` == U+00A9. That would be 00A9 in UTF-16, or C2A9 in UTF-8. In decimal numerals, those values would be "169" or "49833". None of these values appear in the string "-62-8711097109". Nonetheless, if the string is encoded in UTF-8 (meaning **some** of the values are 2-byte, as you say), then none of the bytes should have a 0 value, which means you're OK with `'\0'` as a terminating condition.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option would be a `std::stringstream`:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    stringstream numbers;
    for(int i=0; i < 10; ++i){
        numbers << i;
    }
    cout << numbers.str() << endl; // prints "0123456789"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<sstream>

std::stringstream sout;
while (twenty_byte_buffer[x] != '\0') // While the string isn't at the end...
{
   cout << int(twenty_byte_buffer[x]); // show me, works fine

   sout << int(twenty_byte_buffer[x]); //concatenating into stringstream!

    x++;
} 

std::string str = sout.str(); //get the string value!
cour << str ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The right answer depends on what's really inside your `twenty_byte_buffer`.

If the values in `twenty_byte_buffer` are ASCII characters that represent integers (having the values '0' through '9', inclusive), then the stringstream solution that [Daniel Gallagher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557958/daniel-gallagher) posted would need to be revised slightly, removing the `(int)` cast:

```
stringstream sstr;
int x = 0;
while (twenty_byte_buffer[x] != '\0')
{
    // Note no cast to int here...
    sstr << twenty_byte_buffer[x];
    x++;
}

string result = sstr.str();
```

But if the bytes in the buffer represent binary integers (having the values [-128 - 127], inclusive), then the `while` condition appears to be wrong: The loop will exit on the first 0 value that it encounters! (To use unsigned integers, in the range [0 - 255], change the cast to `(unsigned int)`.)

By the way, the reason why your `char toBuffer` solution didn't work is twofold:

1) You need to use an array of chars, not a single char. You could declare toBuffer as `char toBuffer[100]`, for example (and then be sure to initialize at least the first char to `'\0'`.)

2) The `strcat` would still fail if the bytes represent binary values (unsigned ints in the range [0..255], or ints in the range [-128..127]). You need a call that converts those values to their binary representation. One way of doing this uses the non-standard but commonly-supported `itoa` call:

```
char toBuffer[100];
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

// I think we still need a different terminating condition...
while (twenty_byte_buffer[x] != '\0') {
    itoa(bytes[x], &toBuffer[y], 10));
    y += strlen(&toBuffer[y]);
}
```